# What to do with old questions that are off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic, old-questions

I often see old questions (from the time before superuser.com and serverfault.com) that are offtopic. But they are not closed.

It doesn't make sense to vote-close on them, since no one else will see the question and vote-close, so it will never get five votes.

What should I do with old questions that are off-topic?

Does it make sense if I flag the question for the moderator, or will this just be noise for the moderators?

Comment: "no one else will see the question". Our great god, Google, won't be bothered by time distance.

Comment: Moderators have enough to do. Use your close votes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta). See also: [Was this flag lost somehow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187008/165773) - flags to close also push question into review queue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cleaning up old question will not be a noise for the moderators, and also this move would help them locate such questions faster. So just flag the question for moderator's attention and leave the rest to the moderators...