# Was this flag lost somehow?

Tags: discussion, flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311028/data-extract-from-website-url) almost a week ago now, and the flag is still waiting for review (it shows as "waiting for review" in my flagging history)

> [image: My flagging history stats]
>
> [image: The flag in question]

Is there anything I need to do to get this handled faster? Did the flag get lost somehow?

The question originally had only a couple obscure tags on it, so I thought that might have been the problem - but I edited it a couple days ago to add the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) tags, and that doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: Is it showing *waiting for review* in your flagging history?

Comment: @Azik Yes. I've updated the question to make that clearer.

Comment: The unicorns were ordered by BoltClock to burn it because your flag weight is the same as that of a duck

Comment: Did you choose "Other" when flagging?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No, I flagged it as "unclear what you're asking" - you can see it in the image above. I've flagged at least one other question the same way, with no problems.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe it got disputed by reviewers then and due to some bug not showing as such. Well, we need to wait for a mod to check it anyway.

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not technically lost, but flags to close a question are no longer shown in the moderator only queue. Thus, it needs others that have closing privileges to act on it. Your flags were acted upon faster in the past because the diamond moderators serviced them in turn, but they should only be handling *exceptional* cases, not simply questions that haven't gotten enough velocity to close.

Keep flagging as you see stuff that you think needs closing, don't worry too much about what happens to it after that - beyond of course making sure that you're flagging appropriately.

Comment: "no longer shown in the moderator only queue" - that's a major change, was it announced somewhere?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well, if not it's announce now :) I _believe_ it was mentioned in a few places as part of the larger changes we've been rolling out, but I don't think an individual post was written just to go over it.

Comment: @TimPost It was mentioned that flags now result in the question being put in the close vote queue, I don't think it was mentioned that it no longer shows up in the moderator queue *as well*.  I was under the impression that at least for some period of time they went into both queues.

Comment: Nothing about it in [the blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/).

Comment: We've repeatedly said we were gonna do this since the new review queues were introduced... It just took a while, @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: @Shog9 fair enough. So suppose I flag for closure and see it's still not closed week/month/year later, how to "bump" the flag as I can assume for sure it's lost among the 50,000 other flags? (speaking from the point of view of <3K user)

Comment: @Sha: that's hard to answer in the general case; how important *is* it that the question be closed? The easy answer is: get 3K, vote on it. Another option would be going back and custom flagging it, but this rather defeats the purpose unless *someone is dying*.

Comment: @Shog9 I think this will lead to much less questions getting closed; how good or bad this is I can't really say though. Only time will tell!

Comment: That's something I'm keeping a sharp eye on, @Sha

Comment: @TimPost thanks for the explanation, but that still doesn't entirely explain this, because it's not just older flags that were acted on faster. I've raised over 20 flags since this one, and they've all been handled in a couple hours or so.

Comment: I'm not overly concerned about this post. Certainly nothing that warrants a custom flag or anything. I was just checking on my previous flags to ensure I'm on the right track with my flagging, and I noticed this one. It still looks (to me anyways) like some sort of a bug - unless it's just a combination of the bad tags leaving it ignored for a couple days, and then now that it's older it gets pushed down in the queue backlog and even the good tags aren't enough to get it pulled out?

Comment: @Shog9 Are flags to close still shown in the 10k tools?

Comment: No, @hichris123

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are [huge close votes review queue on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151833/187824). Your flag is one of them. And all close votes question comes in [random order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79634/187824). That's the reason why your flag is not handled yet.

Wait and hope for the best.

Comment: Then why would all my other flags have been addressed in no more than a day or so at the most? I understand reviewers often filter the close-vote queue by tag, but shouldn't my adding the extra tags have helped if that was the problem? Is the queue working with a snapshot of the tags that perhaps doesn't get updated when new tags are added?

Comment: Because other users closed your previously flagged questions direct from the post page. I can guess it.

Comment: Most of the review queues don't have an entirely random order.  They are biased to return more recent items over older items, although there is still some randomness applied so that multiple people aren't always reviewing the same item.  The post you linked to is from the old review system and is no longer relevant.