# Breakdown of questions in VTC queue

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

I was looking at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186955/was-this-flag-lost-somehow/187008#187008) about flags being shown in the VTC queue. I was wondering if flags counted as a significant part of the VTC queue, as the queue is over 100K.

It would be nice to get some rough numbers on this, as it would be interesting to see how many questions have actually been voted to close instead of just being flagged.

It would also be interesting to see a rough breakdown of other information, such as how many questions have 4 close votes, or how many just have one close vote, and also statistics such as average amount of time in queue, and other statistics such as this.

Comment: Might be better to ask "what is the breakdown by number of close votes for items in the VTC queue", gives a slightly bigger picture.  There are things such that they have 5 flags and 1 close vote - how should that count?

Comment: @MichaelT Wasn't thinking, that would be good data too. I'll add that.

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207310/how-many-posts-in-so-cv-queue-arent-eligible-for-vote-expiration-ie-have-no-vo/208486#208486) by [Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) - *"There are currently 12,533 review tasks in the close review queue that are there only because of flags."* Nov21

Comment: @JoshC Thank you, didn't see that answer.

Comment: Whoa. So we've breached the 100K mark?

Comment: Why the downvote? It's an information request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Questions in the queue that have *only* been flagged

13,236 as of Dec. 5, 2013 5:58 UTC

See also: [How many posts in SO CV queue aren't eligible for vote expiration, ie have no votes, only flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207310/how-many-posts-in-so-cv-queue-arent-eligible-for-vote-expiration-ie-have-no-vo/208486#208486)

#### Questions in the queue by number of close votes

```
votes  posts     
------ ----- 
4      4199  
3      11762 
2      24327 
1      47720
```

For a breakdown by flags + votes, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199879/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut/209774#209774

#### Average time spent in the queue

- For all tasks in the close queue now or in the past: **44 days** (and counting)
- For all tasks reviewed in the close queue in the past: **3.5 days**
- For tasks created and reviewed in the past 90 days: **0.8 days**
- For tasks created and reviewed in response to flags reviewed in the past 90 days: **1.3 days**